# What happened to the spiders in this "Dr. Who" episode?

Tags: plot-explanation, doctor-who

In the October 28 episode of Dr. Who, titled [*Arachnids in the UK*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arachnids_in_the_UK), a group of spiders are lured into a vault. What happened to them after? Was the plan to lock them up and let them die of hunger or [cannibalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider_cannibalism#Non-reproductive_cannibalism) each other?

Wikipedia article states:

> To kill them humanely, the group lure the offspring into a panic room..

Was there a discussion in the film of this method, or it was assumed to be best course of action?

Comment: I wondered that too, as I watched it. I came to the conclusion that "lock them up & forget them" was some kind of "non-aggressive, acceptable policy" that I actually wasn't comfortable with in-universe or out-. I'm keen to see any enlightened answers to this.